# Backbone rerender vs jquery remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, backbone.js

I was going through a backbone tutorial, and come to know on following code piece where tutor was removing one `model` from a `collection` and updating UI

```
var PersonsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.model.on('add', this.addPerson, this);
        this.model.on('remove', this.removePerson, this);
    },
    addPerson: function(person) {
        var personView = new PersonView({model: person});
        this.$el.append(personView.render().$el);
    },
    removePerson: function(person){
        this.$('li#' + person.id).remove();
    },
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.model.each(function(record) {
            var personView = new PersonView({model: record});
            self.$el.append(personView.render().$el);
        });
    }
});
```

In the function

```
removePerson: function(person){
    this.$('li#' + person.id).remove();
},
```

he is searching for `songId` in DOM and removes it from UI using jQuery.

My question is what is a faster method to do this task ?

```
this.$('li#' + person.id).remove();
```

where whole DOM tree will be parsed to search element and remove it
or

```
this.$el.html('');
this.render();
```

Where whole view is removed and re-rendered

BTW, I am totally new to backbone so please go easy

Comment: It (as usual) depends. I'd actually go a third route: find the corresponding `PersonView` and call [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) on that.

Comment: Obviously searching through and existing thing will be way better than destroying the whole thing and recreating the whole thing with 1 less node, don't you think?

Comment: Why down-vote to this question ?   Can you please inform what is wrong in this question ?  I was just asking which is most efficient and fastest way ?

Comment: @TJ, I thought browser is internally does same thing(remove one node and rerender all without that node) when we remove any node.

Comment: @SaurabhBayani when you execute `this.$el.html('');` how can the browser possibly know your intention is to render the existing thing without  one node in future..?

Answer (score 1):

From the  [backbone website](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar)

> If jQuery is included on the page, each view has a $ function that runs queries scoped within the view's element... It's equivalent to running: view.$el.find(selector)

So the - `this.$(...)` - selector only parses the view's element, and not the whole DOM. I would stick with the first way.